# Errors:TopLevel vhdl on Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 
entity TopLevel is
Port ( reset : in std_logic;
clock : in std_logic;
coin : in std_logic;
push : in std_logic;
count1 : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)

); 
end TopLevel;
architecture Modular of TurnstileDetector is
signal unlock : std_logic;
begin
controller: entity   TurnstileDetectorController
Port map ( reset => reset,
clock => clock,
coin => coin,
push => push,
unlock => unlock 
);
counter: entity work.counter
Port map ( reset => reset,
clock => clock,
cen => unlock,
q => count1
);
end architecture Modular;
```

Errors:
** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.turnstiledetector.

** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/TopLevel.vhd(14): VHDL Compiler exiting

Comment: How errors can be solved?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. In order to help you, you should provide a clear question. More information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `architecture Modular of TurnstileDetector is` to `architecture Modular of TopLevel is`